# Get the values of multiple constants of a given equation with some data

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Note: This question may have been asked before, I couldn't find it in the quick finder. And my math classes are too far away for me to remember.

I have a the following equation:
$P(h)= P(0)*(1-\frac{a*h}{b})^c$, where: $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constant that I want to find.
I have a table with multiple values of $P$ given $h$.

How do you get the values of these constants?

Comment: I will have other types of equations in the future but I wanted to get the method on one of them to get started.

Comment: h = 0 /= p(0) implies 2a =  -b.

Answer (score 0):

The constants $a$ and $b$ are redundant. Let $d=a/b$. Now for each pair of values (input, ouput), you have 1 equation with two unknowns ($c$ and $d$). If the data follows the formula exactly, just take 2 input-output pairs and you should be able to solve for $c$ and $d$ with two equations, since you have two unknowns. If the data does not follow the formula exactly, but with some randomness, the answer is more complicated.

There is no way for you to figure out what $a$ and $b$ are specifically (though there are infinitely many correct choices), since the only thing that actually matters is their quotient ($d$).